N choose r possibilities as increasing binary numbers
I am looking for a function that inputs (n,r) and outputs the all the ways in which we can pick r objects from a string of n objects. Moreover, I would like this list as an increasing, binary sequence.
For example:
(5,2)
would output: [00011,00101,00110,01001,01010,01100,10001,10010,10100,11000]
I have tried to do this by considering the rightmost 1 and checking whether it can 'move left without bumping into another 1'. If it cannot, then I move to the next 1 and check the same thing. If any of the 1's can be 'moved to the left', every 1 to the right of it gets 'reset'.
Although my code has not been working trying this method.

What do you mean with "binary sequence" and "output"? Your [00011,00101,00110,01001,01010,01100,10001,10010,10100,11000] is not valid Python, is a syntax error.

@nocomment They would be strings

Please edit the question accordingly.

"Although my code has not been working trying this method" - It should have, the method sounds right. But we can't debug code you're not showing.

Your desired order is simply the lexicographic order emitted by itertools.combinations when choosing n - r positions for 0s from n positions:
from itertools import combinations

def binary_combinations(n, r):
    for c in map(set, combinations(range(n), n - r)):
        yield ''.join('0' if i in c else '1' for i in range(n))

print(*binary_combinations(5, 2), sep='\n')

This outputs:
00011
00101
00110
01001
01010
01100
10001
10010
10100
11000

Demo here

How would I get this outputted as a list? Sorry, I am unfamiliar with 'yield'

print(list(binary_combinations(5, 2)))

The combinations function from the itertools library may be helpful. Here is my attempt:
from itertools import combinations

def get_binary_strings(n, r):
    res = []
    for comb in combinations(list(range(n)), r):
        num_decimal = sum(2**pos for pos in comb)
        num_binary = bin(num_decimal).replace("0b", "")
        res.append(str(num_binary))
    res.sort(key=lambda n: int(n, 2))
    res = ['0'*(n-len(s))+s for s in res]
    return res

for s in get_binary_strings(5, 2):
    print(s)

Demo Here

Implementing your question's flip-the-rightmost-01-and-reset-the-rest:
def binary_combinations(n, r):
    comb = '0' * (n-r) + '1' * r
    while True:
        yield comb
        a, b, c = comb.rpartition('01')
        if not b:
            return
        comb = a + '10' + c[::-1]

print(list(binary_combinations(5, 2)))

Attempt This Online!

Start with the 1s, then insert the 0s, but only as last 0:
def binary_combinations(n, r):
    combs = ['1' * r]
    while r < n:
        r += 1
        combs = [
            c[:i] + '0' + c[i:]
            for c in combs
            for i in range(c.rfind('0') + 1, r)
        ]
    return combs

print(binary_combinations(5, 2))

Attempt This Online!
Inspired by the multiplicative formula (for how to get the next combs from the current) and
blhsing's answer (for thinking in terms of placing the 0s instead of the 1s).
Recursive version, maybe clearer:
def binary_combinations(n, r):
    if r == n:
        yield '1' * n
        return
    for comb in binary_combinations(n-1, r):
        for i in range(comb.rfind('0') + 1, n):
            yield comb[:i] + '0' + comb[i:]

print(list(binary_combinations(5, 2)))

Attempt This Online!
